# UDP server send packet not over multicast ip with boost asio

Tags: boost, udp, boost-asio

I'm beginner with boost::asio and udp networking system.

I'm trying to receive many of packet from multicast(239.255.255.251:5353) and I want to send packet multicast(239.255.255.251:5353) for specific device.

I referenced this example from boost

```
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp
```

and I modified that

```
    void handle_receive_from(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                         size_t bytes_recvd)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        if(mdns_validate_name(data_, bytes_recvd))
        {
            std::cout.write(data_, bytes_recvd);
            std::cout << std::endl;

            /** make packet for send **/


            socket_.async_send_to(
                    boost::asio::buffer(data_, length), multi_endpoint_,
                    boost::bind(&receiver::handle_send, this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            socket_.async_receive_from(
                    boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), multi_endpoint_,
                    boost::bind(&receiver::handle_receive_from, this,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
  }
}
```

my problem is packet not over multicast(239.255.255.251:5353). it just sent specific ip(192.168.0.168). I checked wire shark.

I want to send packet again over multicast (239.255.255.251:5353).

please comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately UDP multicast sending and receiving are completely different.

A receiver uses a *local* address to select the receiving device: usually set to `any`. Whilst a sender requires a *remote* address, i.e. the multicast address. In your case that would be `239.255.255.251`.

E.g. from the `boost::asio` [sender](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/multicast/sender.cpp) example:

```
class sender
{
public:
  sender(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const boost::asio::ip::address& multicast_address)
    : endpoint_(multicast_address, multicast_port),
      socket_(io_service, endpoint_.protocol())
  {}
.
.
.
private:
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_;
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;
};
```

BTW the `boost::asio` UDP example that you reference is very old and for a *receiver*!
The latest `boost::asio` UDP *sender* example is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/multicast/sender.cpp). However, for your purposes the [echo server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp) would be a better starting point.

If you want to see complete example of `IPv4` and `IPv6` UDP `asio` comms then have a look at `udp_adaptor.hpp` [here](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib/tree/master/include/via/comms).